# C# web service get data from sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services

I connected SQL server database and I using username and password value return xml boolean true. But I want to get `sicilKod` value according to the results of the username query. How can I do it?

This returning boolean value according to username and password

**[WebMethod]**

```
public bool login(string unamePI, string passPI)
{
    DataTable mytable = new DataTable();
    bool mydeger = false;
    mytable = GetTableWithQueryParams("select * from UYE where USERNAME ={0} and PASSWORD={1}", unamePI, passPI);

    if (mytable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        mydeger = true;
    }
    else
    {
        return mydeger;
    }
    string de = mytable.Rows[0].ToString();
    return mydeger; 
}
```

**Database connect:**

```
public static DataTable GetTableWithQueryParams(string SQLCommandText, params object[] myParametres)
{
    string aConnectionString = "Data Source = ..; Initial Catalog = mydatabase; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = ..; Password = ..";
    SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(aConnectionString);
    SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand("", SqlConn);
    DataTable MyTable = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        int i = 0;
        SqlConn.Open();
        foreach (object MyObject in myParametres)
        {
            if (SQLCommandText.Contains("{" + i.ToString() + "}"))
            {
                SQLCommandText = SQLCommandText.Replace("{" + i.ToString() + "}", "@Prm" + i.ToString());
                MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Prm" + i.ToString(), MyObject);
                i++;
            }
        }
        MyCommand.CommandText = SQLCommandText;
        SqlDataReader MyReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader();
        MyTable.Load(MyReader);
        SqlConn.Close();
        MyReader.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(SQLCommandText + "\n" + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        SqlConn.Dispose();
        MyCommand.Dispose();
    }
    return MyTable;
}
```

Comment: did you try set `de` variable to mytable.Rows[0]["SicilKod"].ToString() ?

Comment: Learn how to explain your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your method to this.

```
public string login(string unamePI, string passPI)
{
    DataTable mytable = new DataTable();
    string result = "";
    mytable = GetTableWithQueryParams("select * from UYE where USERNAME ={0} and PASSWORD={1}", unamePI, passPI);

    if (mytable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        result = string.Format("Welcome {0}", mytable.Rows[0]["sicilKod"].ToString());
    }

    return result;

}
```

then check if login method return value is empty or not.

Comment: System.ArgumentException: 'sicilKod' s&#252;tunu,  tablosuna ait değil.
   konum: System.Data.DataRow.GetDataColumn(String columnName)
   konum: System.Data.DataRow.get_Item(String columnName)
   konum: LoginCpm.WebService1.login(String unamePI, String passPI)

Comment: @EmreAslan does sicilKod exist in UYE table?

Comment: Yes I have sicilKod.I sending values from android application username and password.If it have user then it doing login app.

Comment: But I want to get according to the results of the query.If it true then it get username

Comment: @EmreAslan  Emre, sicilKod bu kaynağın içinde bulunadı diyor. sicilKod alanının UYE tablosu içinde olduğuna emin misin?

Comment: Ben username ve password ile android uygulamasından sorgulama yapıyorum.Eğer kayıt varsa bana true döndürüyor.Bende istiyorum ki eğer true dönerse o sorgulanan kullanıcının adı soyadını alayım

Comment: @EmreAslan tamam anladım sorununu. ancak tablodaki alanları bulamıyor benim yazdığım method. bu adı ve soyadı hangi alanlara denk geliyor yazar mısın?

Comment: Adı USERNAME şifre PASSWORD ile sorgulayıp unamePI ve passPI ile gönderiyor.Tarayıcı da unamePI ve pass a göre sorgulama sonucu  xml true dönüyor.SQL de 4 alan var biri id Username password ve sicilkod

Comment: Yeni bir metod mu yazılması gerekiyor.Bu dönen true değişkene göre o kullanıcının adını nasıl alabilirim.Çok zorlandım

Comment: @emreaslan  string yaptım zaten o yüzden ben methodu. ama burda bir case sensetive durumu var galiba yani büyük küçük harf olayı. cevabı güncelledim bir tekrar bakar mısın?

Comment: Çok teşekkür ederim oldu

Comment: @EmreAslan rica ederim. CPM'de mi çalışıyorsun?

Comment: Evet nereden biliyorsunuz

Comment: @EmreAslan gönderdiğin hata kodunda gördüm :) **LoginCpm.WebService1**